# How to run make in several threads?

Tags: multithreading, makefile

In `OpenCV` docs I met the following text:

> From build directory execute make, it is recommended to do this in several threads

Is it just easy thing?

Comment: Google it, make multi thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make supports the `-j` option to use multiple threads:

> ## `-j` [*jobs*], `--jobs`[`=`*jobs*]
>
> Specifies  the  number  of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more than one `-j` option, the last one is effective.  If the `-j` option is given without an argument, make will not limit
>               the number of jobs that can run simultaneously. When make invokes a sub-make, all instances of make will coordinate to run the specified number of jobs at a time; see the section *PARALLEL  MAKE  AND
>               THE JOBSERVER* for details.